# Filtering XML based using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml and want to filter out sections that I do not need. Here is the xml & respective expected out put,

```
    <CD>
  <RT></RT>
  <author></author>
  <component>
    <structurebody>
      <component>
        <section>
          <templateid root = "1" />
        </section>
        </component>
        <component>
          <section>
            <templateid root = "2" />
          </section>
        </component>
        <component>
          <section>
            <templateid root = "3" />
          </section>
          </component>
        </structurebody>
    </component>
  </CD>
```

I want the output to contain sections with template id's 1 and 3 not 2. I am trying the following xslt but it does not work. It outputs everything. Not sure what is wrong

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/component/structuredBody/component/section/templateId[not(@root = '1' or @root = '3')]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone let me know where am I making a mistake? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<xsl:template match="/CD/component/structuredBody/component/section[templateId[not(@root = '1' or @root = '3')]]" />
```

Note this initial `/CD` in the xpath. Also, note this matches `section` not `templateId` (assuming you wish to remove the `section` element, not just the child `template`.

Actually, you can just simplify it to this. Specifying the whole hierarchy is not strictly necessary here.

```
<xsl:template match="section[templateId[not(@root = '1' or @root = '3')]]" />
```